# How to connect/friend other people on Meta apps (Instagram, Facebook) programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there any way to connect with/friend other people on Meta apps (Instagram, Facebook) using Meta's API (or some other way)?

AI assistant said it's possible, but I think it's hallucinating since I have trouble finding it in the docs.